# meta data / tags for bootstrap modals

Tags: seo, google-search, html, meta-tags, bootstrap

I created a website on bootstrap and a lot of content is in the modals (pop ups) of the webpage,

I was wondering how do I tell search engines that for example Contact Us page [www.example.com/#ContactUs](http://www.example.com/#ContactUs) has the relevant description?

If you can only have meta data in the head of the website and I assume you cannot add extensions like that in the meta data.

Was looking into a possibility of implementing meta data in sitemap.xml but not sure how and if that would work. Because I did add the [www.example.com/#ContactUs](http://www.example.com/#ContactUs) to the sitemap, any plausible solutions?